# API development, Bootstrap and jQuery. Good idea to inject them all in user's code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, twitter-bootstrap

We are developing an API, and that API injects HTML code in the user's code. The main idea is that the user has to define a couple of divs and the API just inject the HTML code within them. The idea is simple and it's already developed. It works nice.

The problem is that we are using jQuery and Bootstrap in that HTML code, and we are a little lost in how to treat those frameworks regarding the user's code. Should we inject them inside of his ? We think that could cause some kind of trouble if the user is already using them in his own code... or are we wrong?

Anyway, in my opinion, i consider this solution inelegant and even a little bit crappy. Any smarter way to accomplish it?

Thanks!

Comment: It will be bad. Have fun with CSS clashes and dealing with jQuery running in no conflict mode.

Comment: I'd suggest not using bootstrap, and instead using self-contained pieces of it that won't conflict with anything the user is including. As far as jQuery goes, only include it if a compatible version of it isn't already included, and if possible(and maintainable), avoid including it at all.

Comment: in newer browsers you can use the css scoped attrib on a <style> tag to restrict the CSS rules to applying to the container of the <style> tag only. you can also run jQuery without leaving jQuery behind.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying a bit my doubt. I don't still know how i will do it, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to have jquery and bootstrap, the only acceptable solution for an embeddable widget would be an iframe.

You could write a loader script which places the iframe with your main content onto the page.

I've written a quite extensive article about how to build embeddable widgets and their best practices on my blog here:
http://codeutopia.net/blog/2012/05/26/best-practices-for-building-embeddable-widgets/

(based on a Stack Overflow answer I gave some time ago, but couldn't find the link to it)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems the better way to do it. Thanks for the approach, i will read carefully your article.